# Replace strings in scenario before scenario execution

Tags: node.js, selenium, cucumber, ui-automation, webdriver-io

Say I have the following scenario:

```
Scenario Outline: <testCase> <expectedResult>
  Given I open the site "#"
  When I add the following data to shipment
    | field_name | field_value   |
    | id_1       | <timestamp>   |    # 1570689270595
    | id_2       | <timestamp>   |    # 1570689270595
    | id_3       | <timestamp>   |    # 1570689270595
    | id_a       | <timestamp_2> |    # 1570689272523
    | id_b       | <timestamp_2> |    # 1570689272523
    | id_c       | <timestamp_2> |    # 1570689272523


  Examples:
    | testCase          | expectedResult | timestamp     | timestamp_2   |
    | CORRECT USER INFO | PASSES         | id_$timestamp | id_$timestamp |
```

What I tried doing is to dynamically set the `timestamp` & `uuid` fields to create different ids for each test, as it has to be unique. And I did that by setting the `beforeScenario` hook and manipulating the scenario before its execution, this is the hook's code:

```
beforeScenario: function (uri, feature, scenario) {
    scenario.steps.forEach((step) => {
      if (step.arguments) {
        step.arguments.map((argument) => {
          if (typeof argument === 'string' || argument instanceof String)
            return uniquify(argument);
          if (argument.rows) {
            argument.rows = argument.rows.map((row) => {
              row.cells = row.cells.map((cell) => {
                cell.value = uniquify(cell.value);
                return cell;
              });
              return row;
            });
          }
          return argument;
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

In short, this maps every argument supplied to every step, and replaces (through `uniquify` function) in the argument certain predefined texts like `$timestamp`.

But the problem is that this isn't the correct flow I should be doing, I don't want to replace every argument supplied to each step but to replace the `Example`'s distributed argument to steps in a way that makes ids `1` to `3` identical, and ids `a` to `c` identical.

Answer (score 0):

The proper solution to this issue turned to be far from what you might actually want, which is to clear your database after each iteration for the automated tests, so you won't need to create random or unique numbers/strings in order to maintain unique values in your tests.

But still, knowing how can I modify the inputs for each test/feature/scenario/step would be handy.